# The option "size" in \tkzShowLine[orthogonal=trough ....]

Tags: tkz-euclide

I wish to make closer to point *D* the compass' mark appearing by using `\tkzShowLine[orthogonal....]`. Unfortunately the option `size=` doesn't have any effect as you can see in the following minimal example.

Thx in advance!

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}       

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoints{0/0/A,3/0/B,0/3/C, 1.5/1.5/D}
\tkzDefPointWith[orthogonal](D,B) \tkzGetPoint{E}
\tkzShowLine[orthogonal=through D,size=.5,color=orange,gap=-2](B,C)
\tkzShowLine[orthogonal=through D,size=2.5,color=red,gap=-3](B,C)
\tkzShowLine[orthogonal=through D,size=100,color=green,gap=-4](B,C)
\tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C)
\tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C,E,D)
\tkzDrawLine[color=blue](A,E)
\tkzLabelPoints[below left](A)
\tkzLabelPoints[below right](B,E)
\tkzLabelPoints[above left](C)
\tkzLabelPoints[below](D)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Does the `gap` key do what you want? E.g. `gap=-1.5` instead of `size=2.5`.

Comment: I noticed that the code didn't correspond whole to image. Sorry. I already tested the rule of gap which acts on the last compass' marks of the construction as showed in the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have in this figure four marks of compass.
You can modify the length of the four marks with `length`, then you can modify the distance of the marks on the line (BC) with `size`(Unfortunately I forgot a little piece of code and `size`  is inoperative, even with the latest version.
I modify the code today.
Then it's `gap` the option to modify the distance with the last two marks with D

The next code is compiled with the new version  [here on CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tkz-euclide) with the number version 3.01c. The code below will be introduce in the version 3.02 the next week.
I forgot the coefficient `\tkz@show@size`

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}   

\makeatletter
\def\tkzShowOrthLine{\pgfutil@ifnextchar[{\tkz@ShowOrthLine}{\tkz@ShowOrthLine[]}} 
\def\tkz@ShowOrthLine[#1](#2,#3)(#4){% 
\begingroup
\pgfkeys{show/.cd,  
          ratio   = .75,
          length  = 1,
          gap     = -1,
          size    = 1} 
\pgfkeys{show/.cd,#1}
    \tkzVecKOrth(#2,#3)                
    \pgfnodealias{tkz@OLtmp}{tkzPointResult}
    \tkz@VecKCoLinear[1](#2,tkz@OLtmp,#4)      
    \pgfnodealias{tkzPointCo}{tkzPointResult}
    \tkzInterLL(#2,#3)(#4,tkzPointCo)
    \pgfnodealias{tkzPOpoint}{tkzPointResult}
    \tkzCalcLength(#4,tkzPOpoint)           
    \tkzGetLength{tkz@mathLen}
    \tkz@VecKNorm[1](#2,#3)
    \pgfnodealias{PO@tmp}{tkzPointResult}
    \tkz@VecKCoLinear[1](#2,PO@tmp,tkzPOpoint)  
    \pgfnodealias{PO@tmp2}{tkzPointResult}
    \tkz@VecKCoLinear[-1](#2,PO@tmp,tkzPOpoint)
    \pgfnodealias{PO@tmp1}{tkzPointResult}
    \tkz@VecKCoLinear[\tkz@show@size](tkzPOpoint,PO@tmp1,tkzPOpoint) 
    \pgfnodealias{PO@1}{tkzPointResult}
    \tkz@VecKCoLinear[\tkz@show@size](tkzPOpoint,PO@tmp2,tkzPOpoint)
    \pgfnodealias{PO@2}{tkzPointResult}
    \ifdim\tkz@mathLen pt>10 pt\relax
        \tkz@VecKNorm[1](#4,tkzPOpoint)
        \pgfnodealias{PO@tmp1}{tkzPointResult}
      \else
        \tkz@VecKOrthNorm[1](tkzPOpoint,PO@2)
        \pgfnodealias{PO@tmp1}{tkzPointResult}
     \fi
    \tkz@VecKCoLinear[-\tkz@show@gap](PO@tmp1,tkzPOpoint,tkzPOpoint)
    \pgfnodealias{PO@3}{tkzPointResult}
    \tkzCompass[#1,length=\tkz@show@ratio *\tkz@show@length](#4,PO@1)
    \tkzCompass[#1,length=\tkz@show@ratio *\tkz@show@length](#4,PO@2)
    \tkzCompass[#1,length=\tkz@show@ratio *\tkz@show@length](PO@1,PO@3)
    \tkzCompass[#1,length=\tkz@show@length](PO@2,PO@3) 
\endgroup
} 
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoints{0/0/A,3/0/B,0/3/C, 1.5/1.5/D}
\tkzDefPointWith[orthogonal](D,B) \tkzGetPoint{E}
\tkzShowLine[orthogonal=through D,color=orange,length=.5,size=1,gap=-1](B,C)
\tkzShowLine[orthogonal=through D,color=green,length=.75,size=.5,gap=-.75](B,C)
\tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C)
\tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C,E,D)
\tkzDrawLine[color=blue](A,E)
\tkzLabelPoints[below left](A)
\tkzLabelPoints[below right](B,E)
\tkzLabelPoints[above left](C)
\tkzLabelPoints[below](D)
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]